# Does .NET Framework 4.5 work on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2003

Can anyone tell me if Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is compatible with Windows Server 2003 or not?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No. .NET 4 is the last framework version supported on Windows Server 2003. .NET 4.5 and higher are not supported on Windows Server 2003.

See [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Does this mean that if I built an application (Windows Form or Windows Service) targeting .NET Framework 4.5, it will fail to run, even if both .NET Framework 4 and 4.5 use CLR 4?