# How to install an exe in windows sever 2003 which requires dot net framework 4.5 or later versions?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to install a software in either

- Microsoft windows server RC2 Service Pack 2
- or Microsoft windows server Service Pack 2

How can i do that because Microsoft has stopped product service for windows 2003 since 2012. So i can not download Dot Net Framework 4.5 in that system

Can any one please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the requirements of your app  to be .NET 4.0

Comment: Ok Thanks..I will try and will notify you if need anything .

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you can't, as there is no .net framework 4.5 for windows 2003 as explained here: [Does .NET Framework 4.5 work on Windows Server 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886603/does-net-framework-4-5-work-on-windows-server-2003)

You should upgrade your server or search a version of your softwre that uses an older version of the framework.

I'm sorry

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. Actually we build that software one of our client has windows server 2003 system he wants to install only in that system. So we totally struck.. So i may try to use .NET 4.0 in my app

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that part. Then use .Net 4.0. I hope your software does not use features from 4.5. Rebuild and try again